# how to test flutter_activity_recognition: ^3.0.0 in android Emulator?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Hello guys I want to test the user activity with flutter_activity_recognition: ^3.0.0 on an Android emulator, I made a simulation (user moving between two points in the map ) with the emulator and I implemented the flutter_activity_recognition methods to check the user activity, but the output is always fixed even though the user is moving and the location is changing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the package you are using uses activity recognition, and activity recognition does not only use GPS, it also uses an accelerometer and other tools as well.

Anyway when you check [Android docs](https://spot.pcc.edu/%7Emgoodman/developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) on this it has a note that might be relevant:

> Note: Mock locations have no effect on the activity recognition algorithm used by Location Services. To learn more about activity recognition, see the lesson Recognizing the User's Current Activity.

I highly recommend going through this answer which has some more information  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286931/7462031